# Javascript quiz validation

Tags: javascript, html

My mind has went completely blank. I have the layout of the 3 question quiz that I made. I just cant figure out the Javascript code that I need to use. Once submitting the quiz, it needs to validate that all questions have answers (I dont wanna use alert or prompt saying you didnt do this or that). I wanna style it with like it highlighting red or something. After it is answered I would like it to display the number of correct answers. Say I get 2 out of 3 right. It display I got 2 right (I wanna use innerHTML or appendChild) Here is how I have it set up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Quiz</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>

<form>
<p class="question1">1. Red and Blue gets what color?</p>
<ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">Green</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">Purple</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">Yellow</label><br/>
</ul>

<p class="question2">2. Trick or ?</p>
<input type="text" name="q2" value="treat" id="q2t">

<p class="question3">3. What is the best movie series of all time?</p>
<select>
    <option name="q3" id="q3hp" value="hp">Harry Potter</option>
    <option name="q3" id="q3twi" value="twi">Twilight</option>
    <option name="q3" id="q3star" value="star">Star Wars</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button type="button" id="results">Submit Quiz</button>
</form>
<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Just need some help with this

Comment: you may use [jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get an element of each input (q1, q2, q3) using

```
document.getElementById()
```

Then you can get the value of each element by using the value property and check if it's empty (equals to ''). 
For each empty element you find you can add a red border by creating a css class and adding it to the element using

```
element.className +=' redWarning'
```

And for every filled question you can check if it is right and add one to the right answers counter. 
At the end you get an element by id that will contain the correct answers count and you change its innerHtml property to the counter like so

```
document.getElementById('answersContainer').innerHTML = counter + ' right answers!'
```